# Printing an array in a GUI label in visual studio with C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

So I am trying to figure out how to print out a list of bowling names and scores in my program. It is way simple when using a console.   I am trying to figure out how to print the array into a label on a GUI?   Any suggestions?  I tried if/else if statements but obviously it didn't work.

Here is my form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_9
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declare a reference variable to the class
    private BowlingTeam myBowlingTeam;

    const int MAX = 20;
    const int TWO = 2;
    int size = 0;
    int count = 0;

    //Array to store the names and scores so they can be printed
    string[] nameAndScoreArray = new string[MAX];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myBowlingTeam = new BowlingTeam();//Create a BowlingTeam object with the default constructor
    }

    //ExitToolStripMenuItem1_Click
    //Purpose: To close the application when clicked
    //Parameters: The sending object and the event arguments
    //Returns: nothing
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }



    //Enter Button Clicked
    //Purpose: To store the info in an array when the button is pressed
    //Parameters: The sending object and the event arguments
    //Returns: nothing
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Get info from the text box and store it in a variable
        string aNameAndScore = nameTextBox.Text;
        //Set the name and score 
        myBowlingTeam.SetNameAndScore(aNameAndScore);

        //Get the information from the text box and store it in a variable
        string nameAndScore = myBowlingTeam.GetNameAndScore();

        if (nameAndScore != "")
        {
            string printName = "";
            string printScore = "";

            //Split the string into two separte pieces of data
            myBowlingTeam.SplitAndDisperseArray();

            //Print the name of the bowler in the score box
            string name = myBowlingTeam.GetAName();

            //Change the int into a string then
            //print the score of the bowler in the score box
            int score = myBowlingTeam.GetAScore();
            string strScore = String.Format("{0:d}", score);


            //Store the name and score in an array to use them to print out the 
            //names and scores later
            if (size < MAX)
            {
                nameAndScoreArray[size] = name;
                nameAndScoreArray[size + 1] = strScore;
                printName = nameAndScoreArray[size];
                printScore = nameAndScoreArray[size + 1];
            }

            string strNameAndScore = printName + " " + printScore;

            if (scoreLabel.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabel.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelTwo.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelTwo.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelThree.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelThree.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelFour.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelFour.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelFive.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelFive.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelSix.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelSix.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelSeven.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelSeven.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelEight.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelEight.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelNine.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelNine.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }
            else if(scoreLabelTen.Text == "")
            {
                scoreLabelTen.Text = strNameAndScore;
            }

            //Clear the text box
            nameTextBox.Clear();
        }
        else//If there is nothing in the text box
        {
            //Calculate the highest score and get the bowler's name
            int highestScore = myBowlingTeam.CalcHighestScore();
            string highestName = myBowlingTeam.GetHighestBowlerName();

            //Calaculate the lowest score and get the bowler's name
            int lowestScore = myBowlingTeam.CalcLowestScore();
            string lowestName = myBowlingTeam.GetLowestBowlerName();

            //Calculate the avg acore
            double avgScore = myBowlingTeam.CalcAvgScore();

            //Convert the numbers into strings
            string strHighScore = String.Format("{0:d}", highestScore);
            string strLowScore = String.Format("{0:d}", lowestScore);
            string strAvgScore = String.Format("{0:f2}", avgScore);

            //Display the information in the appropriate labels
            highScoreNameLabel.Text = highestName;
            highScoreLabel.Text = strHighScore;

            lowScoreNameLabel.Text = lowestName;
            lowScoreLabel.Text = strLowScore;

            avgScoreLabel.Text = strAvgScore;

        }
    }

    //Print Scores Method
    //Purpose: To print the names and scores
    //Parameters: An Array
    //Returns: Nothing
    public void PrintNamesAndScores(ref string[] anArray)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:d}", anArray[i], anArray[i + 1]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Nothing
    private void nameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    // nothing
    private void nameTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }


    //Nothing
    private void scoreTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //Nothing
    private void label10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //nothing
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

}

Here is my class code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Project_9
{

class BowlingTeam
{
     const int MAX = 10;

    //local variables
     int sizeOfName = 0;
     int sizeOfScore = 0;

    //Declare Private Data Members
    private string nameAndScore = "";
    private string name = "";
    private int score = 0;
    private string[] nameArray = new string[MAX];
    private int[] scoreArray = new int[MAX];
    private string[] nameAndScoreArray = new string[MAX];

    //Default Constructor
    //Purpose: To set the initial values of an object
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: Nothing
    public BowlingTeam()
    {
        nameAndScore = "";
        name = "";
        score = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            nameArray[i] = "";
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            scoreArray[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            nameAndScoreArray[i] = "";
        }
    }

    //Parameterized Constructor
    //Purpose: To set the values of an object
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: Nothing
    public BowlingTeam(string aString)
    {
        nameAndScore = aString;
        name = "";
        score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            nameArray[i] = "";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            scoreArray[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            nameAndScoreArray[i] = "";
        }
    }

    //Split the Input Method
    //Purpose: To Split up the data in the array
    //Parameters: An array of strings
    //Returns: Nothing
    public void SplitAndDisperseArray()
    {
            nameAndScoreArray = nameAndScore.Split();
            name = nameAndScoreArray[0];
            score = int.Parse(nameAndScoreArray[1]); 

        //Place the name and the score in their one arrays
            PlaceInNameArray(name);
            PlaceInScoreArray(score);
    }

    //Find Highest Score Method
    //Purpose: To find the highest score
    //Parameters: An array of int
    //Returns: An int
    public int CalcHighestScore()
    {
        int highestScore = scoreArray[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfScore; i++ )
        {
            if (highestScore > scoreArray[i])
            {
                highestScore = highestScore;
            }
            else
            {
                highestScore = scoreArray[i];
            }
        }
        return highestScore;
    }

    //Find Lowest Score Method
    //Purpose: To find the lowest score
    //Parameters: An array of int
    //Returns: An int
    public int CalcLowestScore()
    {
        int lowestScore = scoreArray[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfScore; i++)
        {
            if (lowestScore < scoreArray[i])
            {
                lowestScore = lowestScore;
            }
            else
            {
                lowestScore = scoreArray[i];
            }
        }
        return lowestScore;
    }

    //Calulate Avg. Score Method
    //Purpose: To calculate the avg score
    //Parameters: An array of int
    //Returns: An double
    public double CalcAvgScore()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        double avg = sizeOfScore;
        //Add up all of the elements in the array
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfScore; i++)
        {
            sum += scoreArray[i];
        }
        //Divide the sum by the size of the array
        return avg = sum / avg;
    }

    //Set Score Array Method
    //Purpose: To put scores in the score array
    //Parameters: An int
    //Returns: Nothing
    public void PlaceInScoreArray(int aScore)
    {
        scoreArray[sizeOfScore] = score;
        sizeOfScore++;
    }


    //Set Name Array Method
    //Purpose: To put names in the names array
    //Parameters: A string
    //Returns: Nothing
    public void PlaceInNameArray(string aName)
    {
        nameArray[sizeOfName] = name;
        sizeOfName++;
    }

    //Get Name and Score Method
    //Purpose: To get the name and score 
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: A string
    public string GetNameAndScore()
    {
        return nameAndScore;
    }

    //Set Name and Score Method
    //Purpose: To set the name and score 
    //Parameters: A String
    //Returns: None
    public void SetNameAndScore(string aNameAndScore)
    {
        nameAndScore = aNameAndScore;
    }

    //Get Bowler Name Of Highest Score Method
    //Purpose: To get the name of the bowler with the highest score
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: A String
    public string GetHighestBowlerName()
    {
         int highestScore = scoreArray[0];
         string bowlersName = nameArray[0];

         for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfScore; i++)
         {
             if (highestScore > scoreArray[i])
             {
                 highestScore = highestScore;
                 bowlersName = bowlersName;
             }
             else
             {
                 highestScore = scoreArray[i];
                 bowlersName = nameArray[i];
             }
         }
         return bowlersName;
    }

    //Get Bowler Name Of Lowest Score Method
    //Purpose: To get the name of the bowler with the lowest score
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: A String
    public string GetLowestBowlerName()
    {
        int lowestScore = scoreArray[0];
        string bowlersName = nameArray[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < sizeOfScore; i++)
        {
            if (lowestScore < scoreArray[i])
            {
                lowestScore = lowestScore;
                bowlersName = bowlersName;
            }
            else
            {
                lowestScore = scoreArray[i];
                bowlersName = nameArray[i];
            }
        }
        return bowlersName;
    }

    //Print Bowler's Names
    //Purpose: To print the names the bowlers
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: A String
    public string GetAName()
    {
        string name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfName; i++)
        {
            name = nameArray[i];
        }
            return name;
    }

    //Print Bowler's Scores
    //Purpose: To print the names the bowlers
    //Parameters: None
    //Returns: A String
    public int GetAScore()
    {
        int score = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfScore; i++)
        {
            score = scoreArray[i];
        }
            return score;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry.  I just thought the more code the better.  I will do less in the future.

Comment: Post the minimum amount of code necessary for someone to reproduce the problem and help you. Otherwise, the first step is to read through all of your code to try to find the part that matters. Finding the part that matters is _your job_, not _ours_.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? To show players names and they scores? If yes, use any column control...like DataGridView. In addition, I suggest to you to create STRUCT that combines names and scores => create an array of this structs an set it as dataSource of DataGridView

Comment: My friend, LINQ is your friend. C# is not java.

Answer (score 0):

As a general solution, I'd suggest that using LINQ to output a list of one `String` per item and then using `String.Join` to join them into a single `String` is the most succinct option, e.g.

```
myLabel.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, myArray.Select(obj => string.Format("{0}, {1}", obj.Property1, obj.Property2)));
```